# echo selected in html select option if value exists in array

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, select

I have been searching for days and trying everything, but i can't seem to get this working.

Question :
I have a user profile where a user can select some hobbies from a dropdown menu. This user can also edit his profile. On this edit page I would like to display a dropdown where the previously selected hobbies are selected and the rest of the available hobbies option are displayed for selection.

This is the basic code I have so far ( minus all the code that didnt work ). I hope someone can help he out.

```
 $existing_hobby_values = array("Football", "Tennis", "Volleyball");
 $sql = "select hobby from hobbies ORDER BY id ASC";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "<select multiple>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $interesse = $row['hobby'];
                                                    
            //if{$interesse = in_array($existing_hobby_values) echo "selected" inside option }                                  
                                                    
            echo "<option value='$interesse'>$interesse</option>";

            }
            echo "</select>";
            }
```

By the way...I know I should start using PDO instead of Mysqli, but because this project has a deadline I have to finish this before starting with learning PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
echo "<option value='$interesse'>$interesse</option>";
```

to

```
echo "<option value='$interesse' ".( in_array($intresse,$existing_hobby_values) ? "SELECTED ": "" ) .">$interesse</option>";
```

though to be fair, @rept1d's answer should work just fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $interesse = $row['hobby'];
    echo '<option ';
    if (in_array($interesse, $existing_hobby_values)) {
        echo 'selected ';
    }
    echo "value='$interesse'>$interesse</option>";
}
```

And you should definitely do something about your tabulation.